# Out of place pylint message with Python 3.12: "SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('"

Tags: pylint

### Problem:

I'm getting the following warning when running `pylint`, but only when doing so in a `Python 3.12` environment:

`SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('`

The line triggering this warning uses the `effects.normalize` function from the `pydub` package:

`effects.normalize(AudioSegment.empty())`

This can be observed in [this set of jobs](https://github.com/a-rich/DJ-Tools/actions/runs/7342115320). The warnings appear under the `3.12` job [here](https://github.com/a-rich/DJ-Tools/actions/runs/7342115320/job/19990873702#step:7:1), but do not appear in any of the others (e.g. 3.11 [here](https://github.com/a-rich/DJ-Tools/actions/runs/7342115320/job/19990873617#step:7:1)).

What's odd is that [the line that triggers this warning](https://github.com/a-rich/DJ-Tools/blob/python-version-matrix/src/djtools/utils/helpers.py#L366) doesn't seem to be related to the `SyntaxWarning` in anyway -- what am I misunderstanding here?

### Environment:

- `pylint` version `3.0.3`
- `pydub` version `0.25.1`
- `Python` version `3.12.1`

### Minimal working example:

```
"""test.py"""
from pydub import AudioSegment, effects


_ = effects.normalize(AudioSegment.empty())
```

### Output:

```
$ python test.py && pylint test.py
<unknown>:300: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
<unknown>:301: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
<unknown>:310: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
<unknown>:314: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('

--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The code does run, right?

Comment: Yes, it's just a warning. The only changes in the MR are related to expanding the CI to test different Python versions.